# Python multiprocessing queues slower than pool.map

Tags: python, performance, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I recently started experimenting with multiprocessing to speed up a task. I created a script that does fuzzy string matching and calculates scores using different algorithms (I wanted to compare different matching techniques). You can find the full source here: https://bitbucket.org/bergonzzi/fuzzy-compare/src. As input it takes 2 files which are combined into pairs (each line of file1 with each line of file2). For each pair, fuzzy match scores are calculated.

I made 3 versions. Running with the sample data provided in my repo (which consists of 697.340 items after being combined into pairs), I have the following timings:

- Simple single process - 0:00:47
- Multiprocess using Pool.map() - 0:00:13
- Multiprocess using Queues (producer/consumer pattern) - 0:01:04

I'm trying to understand why my Pool.map() version is much faster than my Queue version, which is actually slower than the simple single-process one.

My reasoning for even attempting to using Queues is that the Pool.map() version holds on to the results until everything's finished and only writes to a file at the end. This means that for big files it ends up eating a lot of memory. [I'm talking about this version](https://bitbucket.org/bergonzzi/fuzzy-compare/src/01d400eb3c6ceb292af6e62fbcc4dbfe0600e946/fuzzycompare_multiproc_map.py?at=master) (linking to it because it's a lot of code to paste here).

[To solve this I refactored it into a producer/consumer pattern](https://bitbucket.org/bergonzzi/fuzzy-compare/src/01d400eb3c6ceb292af6e62fbcc4dbfe0600e946/fuzzycompare_multiproc_queues.py?at=master) (or attempted at least). Here I first produce jobs by combining both input files and put them in a queue which the consumers process (calculate fuzzy match scores). Done jobs are put into an out queue. Then I have a single process grabbing done items from this queue and writing them to a file. This way, in theory, I wouldn't need as much memory since results would be flushed out to disk. It seems to work fine but it's much slower. I also noticed that the 4 processes I'm spawning don't seem to use up 100% CPU when looking at the Activity Monitor on Mac OSX (which is not the case with the Pool.map() version).

Another thing I notice is that my producer function seems to fill up the queue properly but the consumer processes seem to wait until the queue is filled up instead of starting to work as soon as the first item arrives. I'm probably doing something wrong there...

For reference here's some of the relevant code for the Queue version (although it's better to look at the full code in the repo linked above).

Here's my producer function:

```
def combine(list1, list2):
    '''
    Combine every item of list1 with every item of list 2,
    normalize put the pair in the job queue.
    '''
    pname = multiprocessing.current_process().name
    for x in list1:
        for y in list2:
            # slugify is a function to normalize the strings
            term1 = slugify(x.strip(), separator=' ')
            term2 = slugify(y.strip(), separator=' ')
            job_queue.put_nowait([term1, term2])
```

This is the writer function:

```
def writer(writer_queue):
    out = open(file_out, 'wb')
    pname = multiprocessing.current_process().name
    out.write(header)
    for match in iter(writer_queue.get, "STOP"):
        print("%s is writing %s") % (pname, str(match))
        line = str(';'.join(match) + '\n')
        out.write(line)
    out.close()
```

This is the worker function that does the actual calculations (stripped out most of the code since it doesn't make a difference here, full source on the repo):

```
def score_it(job_queue, writer_queue):
    '''Calculate scores for pair of words.'''
    pname = multiprocessing.current_process().name

    for pair in iter(job_queue.get_nowait, "STOP"):
        # do all the calculations and put the result into the writer queue
        writer_queue.put(result)
```

This is how I set up the processes:

```
# Files
to_match = open(args.file_to_match).readlines()
source_list = open(args.file_to_be_matched).readlines()

workers = 4
job_queue = multiprocessing.Manager().Queue()
writer_queue = multiprocessing.Manager().Queue()
processes = []

print('Start matching with "%s", minimum score of %s and %s workers') % (
    args.algorithm, minscore, workers)

# Fill up job queue
print("Filling up job queue with term pairs...")
c = multiprocessing.Process(target=combine, name="Feeder", args=(to_match, source_list))
c.start()
c.join()

print("Job queue size: %s") % job_queue.qsize()

# Start writer process
w = multiprocessing.Process(target=writer, name="Writer", args=(writer_queue,))
w.start()

for w in xrange(workers):
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=score_it, args=(job_queue, writer_queue))
    p.start()
    processes.append(p)
    job_queue.put("STOP")

for p in processes:
    p.join()

writer_queue.put("STOP")
```

I've read quite a bit here about multiprocessing being slower sometimes and I know this has to do with the overhead of creating and managing new processes. Also when the job to be done isn't "big" enough, the effect of multiprocessing might not be visible. However in this case I think the job's quite big and also the Pool.map() version seems to prove it because it's much faster.

Am I doing something really wrong when managing all these processes and passing over queue objects? How can this be optimised so that results can be written to a file as they are processed in order to minimise the amount of memory required while running it?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know what's going on with the performance of your queue based system (I haven't looked too hard yet), but to address the memory consumption issue of your `pool` based version, you might try using `pool.imap` to get an iterator yielding the result values as they are computed by the worker processes. In your `map` code, just swap `imap` in for `map` and move the `pool.close` and `pool.join` calls below the loop that writes out the results and you may be set!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion, your solution does solve the memory issue. With imap each process takes less than 100mb and with map they go up to 1GB. However it becomes slower - on my test data I get 34 secs with imap (vs 13 secs with map). Any idea why that might be?

Comment: It may have to do with the `chunksize` parameter. If I understand things correctly, `map` uses larger chunks by default than `imap` does, which can greatly reduce the overhead if the sequence to be mapped over is very long.

Comment: And how would I find the ideal chunksize to optimize performance? Thanks!

Comment: I'd suggest using as large a chunk size as you can without running out of memory. Of course, the largest gains will probably come early (increasing from the default of `chunksize=1` to say, `chunksize=100`), but the overhead should continue to get less the larger you make it. The `map` method computes a default chunksize that is equivalent to `math.ceil(len(iterable) / 4.0 / cpu_count()))`, so that could be a place to start with `imap` too.

Comment: Testing with bigger data, I found that a chunksize of 100 (for this use case at least) provides the best results in terms of speed and memory. The extra processes only take around 3MB. Using the formula you proposed uses too much memory per process (again, in my use case). The main process still uses a lot though (close to 1GB) but that's probably because I'm calculating a big list of almost 10 million items and keeping that in memory. I still couldn't find a way to use map() with a lazy generator instead of a plain list...

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue with your timings is your multithreaded-queue version is missing an optimization.  You made a comment essentially saying that your job_queue fills up before the worker threads start taking jobs from it.  I believe the reason for this is the c.join() you have in #Fill up job queue.  This prevents the main thread from continuing until the job queue is full.  I'd move the c.join() to the end after the p.join()'s.  You'll also need to figure out a way to get your stop flags into the end of the queue.  The combine function might be a good place to put this.  Something along the lines of adding x number of stop flags after it's run out of data to combine.

One other thing to note:
You're writing over you w variable within the scope of your for loop that kicks off the p processes.  As a matter of style/readability/etc, I'd change w to a different variable name.  If you're not using it, an underscore works as a good throwaway variable name.
I.e.

```
for w in xrange(workers):
```

should become

```
for _ in xrange(workers):
```

Long story short, if you move the c.join() to the end, you should get more accurate timings.  Currently, the only thing that's multithreaded is the fuzzy matching of strings.  One of the advantages of having a producer/consumer thread is the consumer threads don't have to wait until the producer thread is finished, and thus, you end up using less memory.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! It makes sense to join the "job feeder" process at the end... I think I was still confused about what join() actually did, it's clear now to me. What I still don't understand very well is your suggestion "You'll also need to figure out a way to get your stop flags into the end of the queue. The combine function might be a good place to put this. Something along the lines of adding x number of stop flags after it's run out of data to combine." - what do you mean exactly? Why x number of stop flags? And how can I detect that I have no more data to combine?

Comment: As your data is coming from files, whenever the files run out, you know that you have no more data to combine.
Your consumer threads will need some sort of signal to know when to shutdown, thus the implementation of "stop" flags.
Whenever a consumer thread pulls a job off the queue and it's a "STOP" or a None or something similar (you'll have to choose what's best for your application) the thread knows it can shut down.
How I did this on a similar application is my producer thread, once it was done creating jobs, produced stop flags equal to the number of consumer threads.